# How do I call an overridden method that was declared after the class calling it?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding

Say I have this code:

```cpp
class A
{
  public:
    A(){};
    
    void some_func(){
      std::cout << 1;
    };
};

class B
{
  A* my_A;
  public:
    B(A* a) : my_A{a} {};

    void use_A()
    {
      my_A->some_func();
    }
};

class C : public A
{
  public:
    C(){};

    void some_func()
    {
      std::cout << 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
  C new_c;
  B new_b(&new_c);
  new_b.use_A();
}
```

Now this compiles just fine, however `use_A()` is calling the original `some_func()`, not the override declared after. How can I do that? I expect the program to print `2`, not `1`.

Comment: "*the override declared after*" There is no override here. Also, `new_c = C();` is not actual C++ code.

Comment: Read up on [`virtual` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)

Comment: If you're coming in from other languages that default to virtual functions, virtual functions incur a small amount of overhead and C++ has a policy of not wasting any time unless the programmer asked for it.

Comment: does it really compile fine? what, for example, is new_c? also, the entire confused code looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Nothing in the shown code overrides anything. Why do you believe that anything should be overridden? Can you explain, in detail, why you "expect the program to print 2, not 1"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `A::some_func()` as [`virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) in order for `C` to override it, eg:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A(){};
    
    virtual void some_func(){ // <--
      std::cout << 1;
    };
};

class B
{
  A* my_A;
  public:
    B(A* a) : my_A{a} {};

    void use_A()
    {
      my_A->some_func();
    }
};

class C : public A
{
  public:
    C(){};

    void some_func() override // <--
    {
      std::cout << 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
  C new_c;
  B new_b(&new_c);
  new_b.use_A(); // prints 2, not 1
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/EehGAm)

Comment: Note that the `override` is optional, but you're a fool not to take advantage of the diagnostics it can give. Chop some other-wise lengthy bug investigations down to, "Why'd my program stop compiling? What do you mean the function didn't override anything? Oh. Well $#!+."

Comment: Also, `override` was introduced in C++11, and not recognised (or, at best, supported experimentally) when using older compilers or when explicitly building for an older standard.   Certainly, better to use if if possible, but [even now] not everyone has that option.